# Restriction on coefficients in basis of smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

If $f \in L^2([0,T])$ then it can be written as
$$
f(t) \triangleq \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} c_i e_i(t),
$$
for some sequence $\{c_i\}$ of real numbers and some Schauder basis $\{e_i(t)\}$ of $L^2([0,T])$ of smooth functions.

My question is there a necessary and sufficient condition on the coefficients $\{c_i\}$ of the basis characterizing $C^1$ functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that will depend from your choice of basis for example for fourier basis (we are in $L^2[0,T]$) we have :

> If $f\in \mathcal{C}^k$ then 
>   $$
> c_n=o\left(\frac{1}{n^k}\right)
> $$

but

> If 
>   $$
> c_n=O\left(\frac{1}{n^{k+2}}\right)
> $$
>   then 
>   $$
> f\in \mathcal{C}^k
> $$

Comment: What is the proof?

Comment: I don't have a proof but you can see more detail in : AN INTRODUCTION TO HARMONIC ANALYSIS by Yitzhak Katznelson

Comment: Thank you very much Hamza!